# While looping integers

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Im new to Linux and Im taking an online course that is driving me nuts. The teacher talks and explains things so fast I cant keep up even if I rewind back. I know this may be so simple to many of you on here but the task I need to do is...

1. Name the script while.sh.
2. Ask the user to enter a positive integer.  You can assume that the user will enter a positive integer (input validation not required).
3. Use a while loop to print all integers from 0 up to and including the integer entered.  Each integer should be printed on a line by itself and nothing else should print.

What do I have to do to make this?

Comment: What have you tried?   How did it not work as intended?  Have you consulted the manual page for the shell in which you are wanting to construct the `while` loop?  Also of interest might be the `read` command.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to construct a while loop, I was able to make the question so when I run the command ./practice it says "enter a positive integer."  But I have no clue what to do next with the 3rd part of the tasks. I dont have a manual its a free program through the college, and the podcasts my instructor has are a mess.  He doesnt go through everything step by step, he just used a file he had open already...I have this so far

Comment: echo -n "enter a positive integer"
read practice

thats all

Comment: The basic contruction of a `while` loop is:  `while [command]; do [commands]; done`.  Does that help at all?

Answer (score 3):

Since your file is to be named `while.sh`, I suppose you'll want to use `sh` syntax.

You'll need:

- a command to read input. Most text utilities can do it (that's what they do by default). `sh` also has a `read` builtin command to read input into a variable.
- a command to write output and prompts. Many commands for that. The `printf` command can do it and is built in most `sh` interpreters, but since here, you want to output several things, you may want to use a command that can do it several times in a loop.
- a way to do integer arithmetics. Several commands for that. `sh` also has that capability built in the language.

As it happens, the `awk` command can do all of the above and does happen to have a `while()` construct.

```
#! /bin/sh -
awk '
  BEGIN {printf "Please enter a positive integer number: "}
  {while(i <= $0) print i++; exit}'
```

Here, you don't actually need `sh`, you could as well write:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {printf "Please enter a positive integer number: "}
{while(i <= $0) print i++; exit}
```

`bc` is another command that has almost all 3. It's lacking the ability  to read user input, though the GNU implementation does support it as an extension:

```
#! /usr/bin/bc -q
"Please enter a prositive integer number: "
n = read()
i = 0
while (i <= n) i++
quit
```

You could also use the shell's `while` construct and call several commands in a loop, but that's [generally considered bad practice](/q/169716), is less efficient and makes for rather ugly code (also if you wanted to validate user input, `awk` provides with much better functionality for that than the shell's internal capabilities (the `case` construct)):

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf 'Please enter a positive integer number: ' || exit
IFS= read -r number || [ -n "$number" ] || exit
i=0; while [ "$i" -le "$number" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$i" || exit
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Beside `sh`, that runs up to 3 + 2 × (*number* + 2) commands (`[`, `read` and `printf`, thankfully built-in most `sh` interpreters)! Compare to the single one command invocation with `awk` or `bc` above.

Also note that several systems have a command called `seq` specifically designed to output sequences of numbers, one per line (like `seq 0 "$number"`). Shell scripting (shells being before all command line interpreters) is before all about calling the right command(s) for the task. It's not about programming, so I find it strange that your teacher would ask you to use a shell's `while` loop.

Comment: is it important that I use a /bin/sh?

Comment: @user218863, that's if you want to force the use of that particular interpreter. You can also remove that line in which case the system will use a shell for you. That should not matter as long as you use standard `sh` syntax as we do here.

Answer (score 2):

Using `vi while.sh`, create a new file with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0

echo "Enter a integer positive number: "
read NUMBER

echo "Numbers from 0 to $NUMBER: "
while [ $NUMBER -ge $COUNTER ]; do
  echo $COUNTER
  ((COUNTER++))
done
```

Then, use `chmod +x while.sh` to give it execution permissions.
Call the script using `./while.sh`, type the integer number and hit enter (no validations). It returns:

```
user@Notebook:/tmp$ ./while.sh 
Enter a integer positive number: 
5
Numbers from 0 to 5: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

It's important that you read the `man` docs for while, read, bash variable and comparison for better understanding.
There are several ways to do this. That is just a simplest one.

[EDIT]
@user218863, replying your comment for the shop list, you can try something this:

```
#!/bin/bash -

echo "Enter items separated by a space:"
IFS= read -r LIST

IFS=' ' # split on space only
set -o noglob # disable glob
for item in $LIST; do
   printf '%s\n' "$item" || break
done >> shopping_list
echo "List:"
cat shopping_list
```

That will create a file named shopping_list with each typed word, and `cat` the file after the loop.
Please, if the answers heleped you, accept then :)

Comment: Thank you so much Eduardo Baitello, that worked perfect.  Think you can help me with one more problem?...i did all 8 of the other situations I was just stuck on that one and one more.  Again its only because the teacher confuses the crap out of me when he talks about these things in his podcasts.  He acts like we are all advanced users from the beginning of the class, this is what I have to do...

Comment: 1. Name the script for.sh.  This script will create a shopping list.

2. Ask the user to enter items separated by a space.

3. Use a for loop to write the items to a file called shopping_list.  You should use >> to append the output to the file, so each time the script is run the list should get longer.

4. After the for loop finishes, display the contents of the shopping list.

Comment: These are my teachers podcasts you can find them on youtube...
https://youtu.be/EXtbWhdpeoQ

Comment: Added to the answer